# PHP unit only checks the first test

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I'm running Laravel, when trying to develop automated there's an issue. I have the following Test:

```
class SubmitSurvivorTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    //Test for submit with missing parameters
    public function testEmptySubmit()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/submit/survivor');
        $response->assertSee('422');
    }

    //Test for submit with complete parameters
    public function testCorrectSubmit()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/submit/survivor?name=Jhon+Doe&age=22&gender=m&latitude=0&longitude=0&water=6&food=4&medicine=9&ammo=4');
        $response->assertSee('666');
    }
}
```

The first one should return true since if i go to /submit/survivor I'll get

```
{"status":"422","message":"The request could not be delivered since it's missing one or more paramters"}
```

The second one should return false since I get

```
{"status":"204","message":"Created successfully"}
```

But still the second one returns true aswell. No matter the value i put into the second assertSee running phpunit always gives me 0 failures. That is true for every other test aswell, it seems to me that it's only validating the first method.

I've tried changing it to

```
public function testEmptySubmit()
{
    $response = $this->get('/submit/survivor');
    $response->assertSee('422');
    $asd = $this->get('/submit/survivor?name=Jhon+Doe&age=22&gender=m&latitude=0&longitude=0&water=6&food=4&medicine=9&ammo=4');
    $asd->assertSee('666');
}
```

And still no failures, but if i change the value in the first one I still get a failure.

Changing the order didn't seem to have any impact, I changed the testCorrectSubmit to above the testEmptySubmit and it still wouldn't work.

If i change it to assertDontSee in the second one it gives a failure, even tho it should return true, the error is too large to even fit into my terminal but is something along the lines of

```
[A ton of lines with html,js and stuff i can't identify]
</script>\n
</body>\n
</html>\n
' does not contain "666".

C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:331
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi\tests\Feature\submitSurvivorTest.php:27

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 6, Failures: 1.
```

I can't even see the "Failed to assert that" but i just assume it's there

Using assertSeeText seems just as weird since

```
public function testCorrectSubmit()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/submit/survivor?name=Jhon+Doe&age=22&gender=m&latitude=0&longitude=0&water=6&food=4&medicine=9&ammo=4');
        $response->assertSeeText('Jhon');
    }
```

returns no erros, but if i change 'Jhon' to '666' it returns an error even tho neither of them are in the page

According to the documentation it should look like

```
public function testCorrectSubmit()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/submit/survivor',[
            'name' => 'Jhon Doe',
            'age' => '22',
            'gender' => 'm',
            'latitude' => '0',
            'longitude' => '0',
            'water' => '6',
            'food'=>'4',
            'medicine' =>'9',
            'ammo' => '4']);
        $response->assertSeeText('Jhon');
    }
```

which works partially, it returns

```
Failed asserting that '{"status":"422","message":"The request could not be delivered since it's missing one or more paramters"}' contains "Jhon".
```

which shows me that it's making the request but it's not sending the GET parameters.

I did everything up to step 3 from @Spacemudd, since I have no idea how to do step 4, now it is sending the GET parameters since now Jhon Doe appears in the DB. But now the phpunit is returning

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi>php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.0.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.{"status":"204","message":"Created successfully"}
```

and that's it, no failures no ok no nothing, but if I go to the survivors table I can see that Jhon Doe was inserted and I guess that's an improvement?

Turns out that it was working as intended. The last weird behaviour was due to the fact that I had other tests that were just as wrong as the testCorrectSubmit. Removing them solved the issue, and now I'll rewrite the correctly.

Turns out that I was wrong again, it seems that even with the correct structure and no other tests testing the complete submit fails. I deleted all my tests, created a new one using php artisan make:test submitSurvivorTest which looks like this

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class submitSurvivorTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testSubmitEmpty()
    {
        $route = route('submit.survivor');
        $response = $this->get($route);
        $response->assertSee('422');
    }
    public function testSubmitComplete()
    {
        $route = route('submit.survivor', [
            'name' => 'Jhon Doe',
            'age' => '22',
            'gender' => 'm',
            'latitude' => '0',
            'longitude' => '0',
            'water' => '6',
            'food'=> '4',
            'medicine' => '9',
            'ammo' => '4',
        ]);
        $response = $this->get($route);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I've put names into my routes file and it looks like this:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Go to Index
Route::get('/', 'Controller@goHome');

//Submit a new Survivor
Route::name('submit.survivor')->get('/submit/survivor', 'SurvivorsController@submit');

//See a survivor, if no survivor id is submited sees all registered survivors
Route::name('request.survivors')->get('/request/survivors', 'SurvivorsController@getSurvivors');

//See statistics from the survivors, like average water per survivor for example.
Route::name('request.survivors.reports')->get('/request/survivors/reports', 'SurvivorsController@getReportsSurvivors');

//Update a survivor location
Route::name('update.survivor.location')->get('/update/survivor/location', 'SurvivorsController@updateSurvivorLocation');

//Flag a survivor as contaminated
Route::name('update.survivor.flag')->get('/update/survivor/flag', 'LogsController@submitFlag');

//Trade items between survivors
Route::name('update.survivors.trade')->get('/update/survivor/trade', 'TradesController@submitTrade');
```

and my submit method is simply

```
public function submit(Request $request){

        //Check if the required variables where sent, and if no it'll return an error
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'      =>  'required',
            'age'       =>  'required',
            'gender'    =>  'required',
            'latitude'  =>  'required',
            'longitude' =>  'required',
            'water'     =>  'required',
            'food'      =>  'required',
            'medicine'  =>  'required',
            'ammo'      =>  'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $result = array('status' => '422', 'message' => 'The request could not be delivered since it\'s missing one or more paramters');
            echo json_encode($result);
        }

        //Create a new survivor
        $survivor = new Survivor;
        $survivor->name = $request->input('name');
        $survivor->age = $request->input('age');
        $survivor->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $survivor->latitude = $request->input('latitude');
        $survivor->longitude = $request->input('longitude');
        $survivor->water = $request->input('water');
        $survivor->food = $request->input('food');
        $survivor->medicine = $request->input('medicine');
        $survivor->ammunition = $request->input('ammo');

        //Save survivor
        $survivor->save();

        //Set the success message
        $result = array('status' => '204', 'message' => 'Created successfully');

        //Save the change into the logs and display the result
        app( 'App\Http\Controllers\LogsController')->submitLog($survivor->id,$survivor->id,"register",$result);
        exit();
    }
```

All the functions work directly into the browser, they just don't work with the automated tests.

As of this moment running returns

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi>php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.0.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..Array{"status":"204","message":"Created successfully"}
```

and by using --testdox-html it seems to me that it stops it's execution even before displaying the result of the first test, which works fine

It seems that running with `--process-isolation` avoids the crashing and the test performs just fine. I've changed all the echo $response to return, as it seems to be better that way. Now it validates the emptySubmit but doesn't validate the completeSubmit

By removing the exit() now the test runs without `--process-isolation` and returns
Failed asserting that '' contains "204".

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:253
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysurvivorapi\tests\Feature\submitSurvivorTest.php:36

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

But was that was fixed by making it so the response is returned directly in the submit method and not in the log. Now it seems to be working properly as it now returns responses based on the validations. I'll develop the rest of the automated tests and see if the problem shows up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your `larvel.log` isn't showing anything out of the ordinary when you finish the test.

---

2. Be sure the route you are calling is not under the middleware `auth` in which case you have to authenticate the user before calling the route.

`$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/submit/survivor');`

Where `$user` could be an instance of your User model class.

---

3. Consider using the helper command `route()` to build the URL.

In your `web.php`, add a name to your route, e.g.

`Route::name('survivors.submit')->get('survivors/submit', 'SurvivorsController@store');`

In your test, it would become like:

```
$route = route('survivors.submit', [
            'name' => 'Jhon Doe',
            'age' => '22',
            'gender' => 'm',
            'latitude' => '0',
            'longitude' => '0',
            'water' => '6',
            'food'=> '4',
            'medicine' => '9',
            'ammo' => '4',
          ]);

$response = $this->get($route);
```

---

4. Use `dd();` in your submit controller/functions then run the test. This will help you to identify where exactly the problem is.

For example to make sure you are receiving the correct session data, you would call `dd(request()->except('_token'));`

Comment: I've added some more inof if you'd be so kind as to look a little bit more into it

Comment: @MatheusD.Lima I'm confused by the `exit();` in your code. Can you please remove it and test.. your test? 

Comment: Which one? All of them?

Comment: @MatheusD.Lima Yes. I believe functions should not have `exit();` at the end. There is always code running after your function ends.

Comment: @MatheusD.Lima Don't use `echo`, always use `return`. Do `return $result;`.

Comment: `I've changed all the echo $response to return, as it seems to be better that way. ` Thanks, i was in doubt about that but you are right, it works way better with return

Comment: If i plan on using the result in the front-end shouldn't it be `return json_encode($result);`?

Comment: @MatheusD.Lima Yeah.